# Reconfigure dependencies when Integration testing ASP.NET Core Web API and EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, entity-framework-core, xunit2

I'm following this tutorial
[Integration Testing with Entity Framework Core and SQL Server](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2016/11/27/integration-testing-with-entity-framework-core-and-sql-server.aspx)

My code looks like this

**Integration Test Class**

```
public class ControllerRequestsShould : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TestServer _server;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly YourContext _context;

    public ControllerRequestsShould()
    {
        // Arrange
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourContext>();

        builder.UseSqlServer($"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=your_db_{Guid.NewGuid()};Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true")
            .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);

        _context = new YourContext(builder.Options);
        _context.Database.Migrate();

        _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseEnvironment(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")));
        _client = _server.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ReturnListOfObjectDtos()
    {
        // Arrange database data
        _context.ObjectDbSet.Add(new ObjectEntity{ Id = 1, Code = "PTF0001", Name = "Portfolio One" });
        _context.ObjectDbSet.Add(new ObjectEntity{ Id = 2, Code = "PTF0002", Name = "Portfolio Two" });

        // Act
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/api/route");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


        // Assert
        var result = Assert.IsType<OkResult>(response);            
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
```

As I understand it, the `.UseStartUp` method ensures the `TestServer` uses my startup class

The issue I'm having is that when my Act statement is hit

```
var response = await _client.GetAsync("/api/route");
```

I get an error in my startup class that the connection string is null.  I think My understanding of the problem is that when my controller is hit from the client it injects my data repository, which in turn injects the db context.

I think I need to configure the service as part of the `new WebHostBuilder` section so that it used the context created in the test. But I'm not sure how to do this.

**ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services
        services.AddMvc(setupAction =>
        {
            setupAction.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
            setupAction.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
            setupAction.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerInputFormatter());
        });

        // Db context configuration
        var connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:YourConnectionString"];
        services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        // Register services for dependency injection
        services.AddScoped<IYourRepository, YourRepository>();
    }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are two options:

#### 1. Use `WebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices`

Use `WebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices` together with `WebHostBuilder.UseStartup<T>` to override and mock a web application`s DI registrations:

```
_server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddScoped<IFooService, MockService>();
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
);

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //use TryAdd to support mocking IFooService
        services.TryAddTransient<IFooService, FooService>();
    }
}
```

The key point here is to use `TryAdd` methods inside the original `Startup` class. Custom `WebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices` is called **before** the original `Startup`, so the mocks are registered before the original services. `TryAdd` doesn't do anything if the same interface has already been registered, thus the real services will not be even touched.

More info: [Running Integration Tests For ASP.NET Core Apps](http://fizzylogic.nl/2016/07/22/Running-integration-tests-for-ASP-NET-Core-apps/).

#### 2. Inheritance / new Startup class

Create `TestStartup` class to re-configure ASP.NET Core DI. You can inherit it from `Startup` and override only needed methods:

```
public class TestStartup : Startup
{
    public TestStartup(IHostingEnvironment env) : base(env) { }

    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //mock DbContext and any other dependencies here
    }
}
```

Alternatively `TestStartup` can be created from scratch to keep testing cleaner.

And specify it in `UseStartup` to run the test server:

```
_server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<TestStartup>());
```

This is a complete large example: [Integration testing your asp .net core app with an in memory database](http://www.stefanhendriks.com/2016/04/29/integration-testing-your-dot-net-core-app-with-an-in-memory-database/).

Comment: How it can override - method ``` public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)``` in ```Startup.cs``` is not ```Virtual``` ?

Comment: @GauravAroraa, just make a base method `virtual`. It doesn't break anything.

Comment: it did not resolve the problem unless, pushed into another issue

Comment: @GauravAroraa,  what is the issue? You just need to execute a correct code inside `TestStartup` class. The way to do it is doesn't matter. It's even possible to pass a variable inside base `Startup` class https://stackoverflow.com/a/44486236/5112433

Answer (score 50):

@ilya-chumakov's answer is awesome. I just would like to add one more option

**3. Use ConfigureTestServices method from WebHostBuilderExtensions.**

The method ConfigureTestServices is available in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost version 2.1(on 20.05.2018 it is RC1-final). And it lets us override existing registrations with mocks.

The code:

```
_server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddTransient<IFooService, MockService>();
    })
);
```

Comment: The best method. Also you can remove some registration, for example `services.RemoveAll(typeof(IHostedService))`

Comment: Before I saw this answer I was putting my dependency injection in .ConfigureServices in my tests. This meant that I had to use .TryAddTransient in my actual code instead of AddTransient. I like this way a lot better.

Comment: Since I updated to .net core 3.0, it looks like I need to delete the previous registration(s) first :-(

Comment: best option, saved the day :D

Answer (score 0):

@Ilya-Chumakov @lilo.jacob, both answeres are in the good path, but I would like to add the final addition that would do answer completly perfect.

If you have

```
.ConfigureServices(services =>
                   {
                       serviceCollection
                      .Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped(typeof(IFooService), a => MockService));
                   }
               )
```

This way if IFooService it's being already added by the Startup, it will be removed and substituted. And in case it's not it will added it.