# NUnit Entity Framework integration test dependency injection issue with .NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, integration-testing

I have just started looking into .NET Core with Entity Framework. I have previously used .NET Framework with Ninject but I'm now trying to use the DI built into .NET Core.

I have a `TestBase` class which my tests will derive from. I want this class to be responsible for creating and deleting a test database using `[OneTimeSetUp]` and `[OneTimeTearDown]`. The problem is that I don't seem to be able to figure out how to gain access to my DI services in the setup and teardown methods. These methods cannot have parameters and my `TestBase` class must have a parameterless constructor so I can't get them from there either.

```
[SetUpFixture]
public partial class TestBase
{
    protected IEFDatabaseContext DataContext { get; set; }

    public TestBase(IEFDatabaseContext dataContext)
    {
        this.DataContext = dataContext;
    }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void TestInitialise()
    {
        this.DataContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void TestTearDown()
    {
        this.DataContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    }
}
```

The above gives the following error:

> `TestBase` does not have a default constructor.

I may well be going about this the wrong way but this is how I've always done things in the past so please let me know if there is a better method when using .NET Core DI.

---

`Startup` class for reference:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration config;

    public Startup(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<TestDataContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(this.config.GetConnectionString("TestConnectionString")),
            ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

        services.AddScoped<IEFDatabaseContext>(provider => provider.GetService<TestDataContext>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reconfigure dependencies when Integration testing ASP.NET Core Web API and EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543319/reconfigure-dependencies-when-integration-testing-asp-net-core-web-api-and-ef-co)

Comment: Thanks @NightOwl888, you helped me find the solution I have just posted.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to NightOwl for pointing me in the right direction. A combination of the Microsoft [article on integration testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing) and the possible dupe question led me to the following solution.

By using the `TestServer` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` I am able to access the DI `ServiceProvider` built in `Startup`.

TestBase:

```
public partial class TestBase
{
    protected readonly TestServer server;
    protected readonly IEFDatabaseContext DataContext;

    public TestBase()
    {
        this.server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
        this.DataContext = this.server.Host.Services.GetService<IEFDatabaseContext>();
    }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void TestInitialise()
    {
        this.DataContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void TestTearDown()
    {
        this.DataContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration config;

    public Startup(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<TestDataContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(this.config.GetConnectionString("TestConnectionString")),
            ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

        services.AddScoped<IEFDatabaseContext>(provider => provider.GetService<TestDataContext>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Integration testing ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing) is well covered by the Microsoft documentation.

Basically, you need to install the [Test Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing#the-test-host) project from NuGet [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost/), then use it to launch the web environment within NUnit.

### Basic Example

```
public class TestClass
{
    private TestServer _server;
    private HttpClient _client;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        // Arrange
        _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>());
        _client = _server.CreateClient();
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _server = null;
        _client = null;
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task ReturnHelloWorld()
    {
        // Act
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal("Hello World!",
            responseString);
    }
}
```

With the `TestServer` it is possible to intervene with the DI configuration and/or the `IConfiguration` to substitute fakes in the configuration. See [Reconfigure dependencies when Integration testing ASP.NET Core Web API and EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543319/reconfigure-dependencies-when-integration-testing-asp-net-core-web-api-and-ef-co).