# WebApplicationFactory use ConfigureServices or ConfiguresTestServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I want to test a ASP.NET Core 6 application. I have created a custom factory as inheriting from `WebApplicationFactory`. In the `ConfigureWebHost` method, do I have to use `builder.ConfigureServices` or `builder.ConfigureTestService` ?

I don't understand the difference.

E.g :

```
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
                .ConfigureTestServices(services => //Or ConfigureServices ?
                {
                    var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                        d => d.ServiceType ==
                            typeof(DbContextOptions<OnDemandContext>));

                    if (descriptor != null)
                    {
                        services.Remove(descriptor);
                    }
                    
                    services.AddDbContextPool<OnDemandContext>(options =>
                    {
                        options.UseInMemoryDatabase("fakeDatabase");
                    });
                });
        }
```

Comment: You could check this issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543319/reconfigure-dependencies-when-integration-testing-asp-net-core-web-api-and-ef-co/50434512#50434512  ConfigureTestServices allows you override existing registrations with mocks  which could be done by WebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to call `builder.ConfigureTestServices` but it will allow you to re-configure, override, or replace previously registered services with something else. It is executed after your `ConfigureServices` method is called.

In the example below, testcontainers are used to replace the normal database connection string provider and a `WebMotions.Fake.Authentication.JwtBearer` is being used to create a fake Jwt bearer token for integration testing

```
    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(FakeJwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddFakeJwtBearer();
        services.RemoveAll(typeof(IHostedService));
        services.RemoveAll(typeof(IConnectionStringProvider));
        var containerString = new ConnectionStringOptions
        {
            Application = "testContainer",
            Primary = Container.ConnectionString
        };
        services.AddSingleton<IConnectionStringProvider>(_ =>
            new ConnectionStringProvider(containerString));
    });
```