# How to inject dependencies into an ASP.NET Core application from another project/assembly for testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, integration-testing

I have an ASP.NET Core application (C#). I run integration tests of it using the NuGet package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost** (v7.0.10).

When running my application in integration tests, I would like to inject some classes defined in the test assembly. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

I start my application approximately like this:

```
var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<StartupLocalIntegrationTest>();
```

Note that I inject a custom startup class, **StartupLocalIntegrationTest** (instead of the regular **Startup**). I hoped I could use this class to inject extra dependencies. But apparently **StartupLocalIntegrationTest** needs to live in the same project as the ASP.NET Core application. If I try to move or copy **StartupLocalIntegrationTest** to the test project, it apparently fails to map the controllers; most or all tests fail with 404 NotFound. (My controller implementations are public, and the test project can see internals anyway, so I don't think that's the problem.)

I can work around it by moving all my test helpers to the project where the application lives, but I would much prefer to avoid that, since that brings in some NuGet dependencies that I don't want there.

What is a good way to inject classes into your ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543319/reconfigure-dependencies-when-integration-testing-asp-net-core-web-api-and-ef-co ... may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use your regular `Startup` class, but you can register additional services for testing using the `ConfigureTestServices` method. This is highlighted in the answer referenced by [Neil W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2936204/neil-w)'s comment above.

It looks something like this:

```csharp
var testClient = 
   new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>()
      .WithWebHostBuilder(builder => {
         builder.ConfigureTestServices(services => {
            // Register test-specific services here   
         });
      })
      .CreateClient();
```